# Como mapear duas entidades iguais com Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, modelo-relacional

Tenho um cenário onde tenho as entidades `Pedido` e `Usuário`. O `Pedido` é composto por alguns atributos, dentre eles o solicitante que é mapeado da seguinte forma:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "usuario_matricula", referencedColumnName = "matricula", nullable = false)
private Usuario solicitante;
```

Porém esse pedido também tem o atendente, que é um `Usuário`. Tento mapeá-lo assim:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "usuario_matricula", referencedColumnName = "matricula", nullable = true)
private Usuario atendente;
```

O problema é que quando tento fazer dessa forma tenho a seguinte exceção:

> br.com.caelum.vraptor.InterceptionException:
>   org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity:
>   com.comunicacao.model.Pedido column: usuario_matricula (should be
>   mapped with insert="false" update="false")

Se eu adiciono o que é recomendado na exceção `(insert="false" update="false")` o erro some. Gostaria de saber se essa linha vai me permitir salvar e editar os dados do mesmo e se essa é a forma correta de mapear duas entidades iguais no `Hibernate`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**`@JoinColumn`** é utilizado para nomearmos a coluna que possui a chave estrangeira requerida pela associação. Se nada for especificado, será utilizado o nome do campo, basta então você alterar o *name* de uma das duas JoinColumn para funcionar.

Ex.:

```
@JoinColumn(name="atendente_matricula")
```

Comment: Nossa, acabei me esquecendo do nome que seria gerado pra relação haha. Muito obrigado, era isso mesmo.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow em Português!  Bem vindo ao StackOverflow em Português. Editei sua publicação para remover as saudações, pois costumamos mantê-las o mais limpo possível para focar na sua dúvida sobre programação. Caso tenha interesse em visitar uma parte do site que não é voltado para tirar dúvidas pode conhecer o [Bate-papo do Stack Overflow em Português](http://chat.stackexchange.com/). Se tiver dúvidas quanto ao funcionamento, regras e procedimentos do site visite o [Stack Overflow em Português Meta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/) :)